# stacked \widetilde and \dot

Tags: math-mode, accents, stacking-symbols

I need to typeset (from bottom up) math bold L with above-dot and widetilde (both centered horizontally above the L), i.e. approximate time-derivative of tensor-valued function.

(I would google more, but being one-handed those days makes it a bit more difficult.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isn't

```
\widetilde{\dot{\mathbf{L}}}
```

working?

Comment: Thanks, and thanks @Mico. I thought the two would not work together in a trivial manner and did not even try.

Answer (score 3):

The `amsmath` package should be loaded in the preamble. Then the following code should do what you need;

```
$\widehat{\dot{\mathbf{L}}}$
```